# When should I use Haskell ORM(-like) libraries?

Tags: database, haskell, orm

I am developing a project which saves some vehicle locations and use them for tracking the vehicles. I have a login service and some other simple location saving and tracking services. I am porting some very similar Python project (written by me) and the Python one is using SqlAlchemy. Using something like Persistent in Haskell version would be easy for me! But some articles discourage using ORM and encourage using something like Hasql. In what conditions using ORM would be better?

Comment: Well, what are your requirements? How large and complex is your schema? Would this result in you having to hand-roll lots of SQL to read/write to the tables?

Comment: atc: Give me some clues to find out how complicated my software is